# can't call dispose() method when app exit

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to call a method to save in SharedPreferences when app exit

i tried dispose() but doesn't work

```
 @override
void dispose() {
  print("exit");
  _subscription.cancel(); 
  saveCounter(); 
  super.dispose();
}

Future<void> saveCounter() async{
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setInt('startNumber', _steps);
}
```

Comment: where do you put dispose method? Is it on statefulwidget?

Comment: @ejabu yes its statefulwidget class return scaffold

Answer (score 1):

- we can wrap `Scaffold` using `WillPopScope`
- we can **execute** *saveCounter* inside the function
- ensure it will return **true** that wrapped inside `Future.value()`

```dart
class WillPopScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  Future<void> saveCounter() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance(); // we can save state
    await prefs.setInt('startNumber', _steps);
  }

  Future<bool> onCloseEvent() async {
    await saveCounter();
    return Future.value(true); // we cannot put "return true"
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: onCloseEvent, // will interrupt our scaffold dismissal
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Will Pop Interrupt'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text("Execute method when Closing"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Fully working repo

You can build it yourself in this [Github repo](https://github.com/ejabu/flutter_tricky_layout/blob/master/lib/n_screen/will_pop_page.dart)

### Demo

[image]

Comment: not working i want it to run when someone close the app

Comment: @suhaibsalem any luck with this ?  I am also looking for the same. How to free resources when   app is removed/closed form  recently opened app tray